# How to route all traffic to a service in Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a virtual service yaml file with below lines.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nodeserver
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - node-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /
    - uri:
        exact: /sample1
    - uri:
        exact: /sample2
    route:
    - destination:
        host: node-service
        port:
          number: 8080
```

Here, Instead of `/sample1` and `/sample2` as two url matches, can I assign something like `*` to route all traffic to node-service by default?
Also, if the webpage has hyperlinks inside it will Istio redirect them by default or need to add any custom configuration for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` instead of `exact` in [HTTPMatchRequest](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPMatchRequest).
That way you can catch all with ECMAscript style regex.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nodeserver
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - node-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        regex: '.+'
    route:
    - destination:
        host: node-service
        port:
          number: 8080
```

Comment: Thank you I will test that and reply back. Also, is there any way to set /page1 as default so that even if user types only istio gateway then it should route the traffic to /page1 also.

Comment: You can use [HTTPRedirect](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRedirect) or [HTTPRewrite](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRewrite) to do that. This is however another question, and if you want a complete solution, you should post new question.

Answer (score 0):

**Use prefix: ''**

This worked for me:

```
  http:
  - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: ''
```